# Given void when taking one element from record array

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Say, I have a record array.

```
RA = array([('professor', 'class1', '1'), ('professor', 'class1', '1'),
       ('professor', 'class1', '0'), ('doctor', 'class3', '1')], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S25'), ('f1', 'S25'), ('f2', 'S25')])
```

It's type is ndarray

```
type(RA) # <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Now, if we want to take one record:

```
type(RA[0]) # <type 'numpy.void'>
```

I know, that it is a normal behaviour according to the documentation.

Can anyone explain, why it is the case? The problem here is that when I have an ndarray, I can extract multiple fields at once, say:

```
RA[['f1','f2']]
```

At the same time, this will not work and will throw an exception:

```
RA[0][['f1','f2']]
```

Of course, I can do as follows.

```
type(RA[0:1]) # <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So, take the first record:

```
t = RA[0:1];
```

And then:

```
t[['f1','f2']];
```

And this will work - it will return me exactly one record, but with ndarray type.

As far as I understand, slicing operations here will return me record array, whereas indexing operation returns void type.

So, questions are:

1. Why it is the case?
2. Is it a normal way to get one record as it was described before?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you add the initial `RA = ...` line...

Comment: Thanks. I've added an example.

Comment: I recommend using `pandas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is consistent with the rest of Python and Numpy.

Whenever you take a slice of something, you should expect to get back that same type as the sliced object. This is true of regular python lists (and tuples, and strings), as well as all Numpy arrays. When you index into an object, you should expect to receive whatever type the element is. e.g.:

```
pylist = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
type(pylist[0:1]) # <type 'list'>
type(pylist[0]) # <type 'int'>

nparr = array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
type(nparr[0:1]) # <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(nparr[0]) # <type 'numpy.int64'>
```

Therefore, you can only perform those operations which are valid for the type which you end up with. In the case of `numpy.void` type, it does not support slicing, so that is why you receive an exception. Although, actually, what you are doing with `RA[0][['f1','f2']]` is [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), but that won't work with `numpy.void` either.

If what you want to do is retrieve the 'f1' and 'f2' fields from the first element then you can do:

```
RA[['f1','f2']][0]
```

You can also use slicing here:

```
RA[['f1','f2']][0:1]
```

This works because you are operating on a Numpy array which supports advanced indexing, and then selecting the element from this returned view (which is of type `numpy.ndarray`).

I should also note, that slicing behavior is not identical between Numpy and native python objects, but that the type of objects they return is consistent.